# md-button clicking on Double tap in iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, angular-material

Actual Behavior:

I am using *md-button*

`<md-button md-no-ink ng-click="showSignUpModal('signup1');" class="md-button md-primary md-raised btn-signup"> TEST </md-button>`

On iOS devices I have to tap twice to get *ng-click* function work. What is the work around for this to fire in 1 tap only? Thanks.

Angular Version: *
1.5.7

Answer (score 0):

I've been hit by this bug as well and have been researching for a while.  Here are two possible fixes. I haven't tested them yet.

First option:

```
 .config(function( $mdGestureProvider ) {
      $mdGestureProvider.skipClickHijack();
  });
```

2nd option: Make a click directive

```
 app.directive('myclick', function() {
     return function(scope, element, attrs) {
         element.bind('touchstart click', function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
             event.stopPropagation();
             scope.$apply(attrs['myclick']);
         });
     };
 });
 app.controller('Main', function ($scope) {

     $scope.anything = function() {

         alert('Hi');
     };
 });
```

Broken

```
 <a href="#" ng-click="anything()">click</a>
```

Fix

```
 <a href="#" myclick="anything()">click</a>
```

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1406

Comment: Ok I've now had a chance to try and fix my own issues regarding this and solution #1 above did the trick!